# MySQL Trigger Update counter of parent_table used by INSERT IGNORE INTO SELECT

Tags: mysql

I'm currently starting to use triggers in my db-structure.
I have to tables - let's call them parent and child.
The trigger is called after an insert to the cild table.
The insert-Statement is

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO child (parent_id)
SELECT
    id
FROM parent
WHERE somecondition = 1
```

The statement in the after-insert trigger of the child table is:

```
UPDATE parent SET derivate_count = derivate_count + 1;
```

The parent table has no trigger on update or something else and I recieve the error:
SQL Fehler (1442): Can't update table 'parent' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

I would understand if this error would occur if I force the same event on the parent-table - how could this be solved?

Kind regards,

Dominik

Comment: Not an answer, but are you counting how many children a parent has? Because is so, the child has a parent_id, so with the right index it would be lightning fast to just do a count on the join of the two tables instead of using a trigger.

Comment: I have nearly 500k rows in the parent-table and the derivate_count is needed realy often ... Calculating it on every call I need it slows the query down like hell :)

Comment: it shouldn't. If you have an index it would take about `log(n)` checks (that's a little over 5). It should take almost no time. You really should try and fix that instead of going with the trigger!

Comment: I did it realtime and within the last weeks the time increased really much.
Mabye because I realized it as a subquery with further conditions?

Comment: This: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM parent p JOIN child c ON p.id = c.parent_id GROUP BY p.id` takes about 0.01 seconds on my machine, with a database of 400k "parents" and about 1M "childs" (they are something else, but serve the purpose).

Answer (score 0):

use OLD.fieldName and NEW.fieldName to refer to the values before and after the update respectively...

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER testref AFTER UPDATE ON parent
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   declare count_ integer;
   select count(*) into count_ from child where parent_id = NEW.id;
    if (if count_ = 0)
       then 
          INSERT INTO child ( parent_id ) values (NEW.id );
          delete from child where parent_id = OLD.id;
          ... more code ...
       else
          ... more code ....
          ... else is optional, but an end to end the if is not.... 
       end if;
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```

Comment: hm - my problem is, that i don't know if the entry already exist in the child-table ... and the counter of the parent should be updated, if the child was inserted successfully

Comment: @DominikHabichtsberg then use the if to check if the entry already exists... look at the example... i even put example code for delete and insert.